# My screen is updated when I click on the visibility icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form, when the screen starts and I get information.
If it is information, I edit it or change it and I click the visibility icon that is found in the textform that says "Password", the same information that appears from the beginning is placed again and not the one that I edited.

```
    Example: In the image I get the word "Josskkk" and I want to change it to "Joss" and after that I click the visibility icon, "Josskk" appears again.
    
I am using  Future Builder

    Help would be greatly appreciated
```

code and image::

```
class crudperfil extends State<CrudPerfil>{
 
 final  Correo =  TextEditingController();
  final  Contrasena =  TextEditingController();

  final NombreUsuario =  TextEditingController();
 bool obscuretext = true;
 Future <dynamic> fup;

  Widget ContrasenaF2(Contrasena){
    return new Container(
        child: new TextFormField(
          controller:Contrasena,
          obscureText: obscuretext,
          decoration:  InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            hintText: 'Ej:123xxx',
            labelText: 'Contraseña',
            suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                setState(() {
                  obscuretext = !obscuretext;
                });
              },
              child: obscuretext == true ?  Icon(Icons.visibility_off,color: Colors.grey,): Icon(Icons.visibility,color: Colors.grey,),
            ),
          ),

        )
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("initstate");
   fup =   editarperfilservices.EditarPerfil() ;
    super.initState();
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(          
              future: fup,
    builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot  snapshot) {
      List  busqueda = snapshot.data;
      if(snapshot.hasData ) {
      return   Center(
          child: new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10,right: 10,// Para que el teclado no este sobre el texto
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: busqueda.length,
    itemBuilder: (context,i){
      Correo.text = busqueda[i].UsuarioCorreo ;
      NombreUsuario.text = busqueda[i].UsuarioApodo ;
      Contrasena.text = busqueda[i].UsuarioContrasena;
      fotousuarioo = busqueda[i].FotoUsuario;
      Id_Usuario =  busqueda[i].UsuarioPk;
      return Container(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
            children:[
             
              SizedBox(height: 18,),
              FullName(NombreUsuario),
              SizedBox(height: 18,),
              CorreoF2(Correo),
              SizedBox(height: 18,),
              ContrasenaF2(Contrasena),
              
            ]
        ),
      );
    }
              )
          )
      );
    }else if(snapshot.hasError){
      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
    } return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator()
    );
    }
          ),
        )

} 
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLj79.png)

Comment: this is one of the reasons why fetching data should be done outside of the widget. In most cases, inside repositories. because every time your UI refreshes, the futurebuilder will also get restarted. same is true with stream builders.

Comment: the job of the UI should only lay out the UI base from the data fetched by your repository. So what I can say is you have to reconsider your app architecture to avoid errors like this.

Comment: How should the architecture of the code be? any example with the code i posted?

Comment: for info about app architecture check this out https://courses.codewithandrea.com/courses/783023/lectures/14570533

Comment: [here](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-app-architecture-riverpod-introduction/) is another article for app architecture.